# Collinearity of three points

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors, 3d

In my book its given , three points A,B,C with position vectors a,b,c are collinear if and only if there exists scalars x,y,z not all zero simultaneously such that xa + yb + zc = 0, where x + y + z = 0.

Surprisingly, this is also the condition for coplanarity of three vectors. But All COPLANAR vectors are NOT collinear . So where is the the flaw in my argument ?

Comment: Your first statement is saying the three **points** are collinear, not the three vectors.

Comment: Foe eg. x[5,-10,15] + y[2,3,-4] +z[0,-7,10] = 0 where x,y,z are scalars have solution x = 2,y = -5, z=-5. which implies that they should be collinear. But when we plot them we clearly see that they are not collinear.

Comment: Isn't it possible that you're learning about the *projective plane*?

Comment: @Niescte the example you give does not satisfy the condition x + y + z = 0, which is why those points are not colllinear.

Comment: Ok i think i've got it now.
For coplanarity the condition is that ax + by + cz = 0 for scalars x,y,z where not all x,y,z = 0 , but for collinearity there is an additional condition that x + y + z = 0   so that one point can be shown to to divide the other two points in some ratio . Am i right now ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i think i've got it now.
For coplanarity the condition is that ax + by + cz = 0 for scalars x,y,z where not all x,y,z = 0 , but for collinearity there is an additional condition that x + y + z = 0   so that one point can be shown to to divide the other two points in some ratio .

Answer (score 1):

As you write, vectors $a,b,c$ are coplanar iff there are scalars $x,y,z$, not all $0$, such that $xa+yb+zc=0$, i.e. iff they are linearly dependent.

The *endpoints* of $a,b,c$ are collinear iff $c-b$ is parallel to $c-a$, that is, $c-a=t(c-b)$ for some scalar $t$, assuming $b\ne c$.
But then $1a+(-t)b+(t-1)c=0$ and these coefficients sum up to $0$.

Conversely, if $xa+yb+zc=0$ with $x+y+z=0$, then either $x=0$ whence $y=-z$ and $b=c$, or we can divide by $x$ and set $t=-y/x$ to conclude $c-a=t(c-b)$.